# Why does Google Pay client isReadyToPay method return false in Web view on Android but true in Web browser?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-play-services, google-pay

Google Pay client `isReadyToPay` method always returns `true` in the Web browser but `false` in the Web view when run on an Android device. It is the sandbox TEST environment.

The payment method

```json
{
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "apiVersionMinor": 0,
  "allowedPaymentMethods": [
    {
      "tokenizationSpecification": {
        "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
        "parameters": {
          "gateway": "worldpay",
          "gatewayMerchantId": "obfuscated"
        }
      },
      "type": "CARD",
      "parameters": {
        "allowedAuthMethods": [
          "PAN_ONLY",
          "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"
        ],
        "allowedCardNetworks": [
          "AMEX",
          "DISCOVER",
          "INTERAC",
          "JCB",
          "MASTERCARD",
          "VISA"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Client code (ReactJS)

```
export const GooglePayContext = React.createContext({})

const GooglePayContextProvider = ({
  children,
  supportedCardBrands: supportedCardBrandsPromise,
}) => {
  const [paymentsClient, setPaymentsClient] = useState()
  const supportedCardBrands = usePromise(supportedCardBrandsPromise)

  const handleReady = () => {
    if (!window.google?.payments) {
      return
    }

    setPaymentsClient(
      new window.google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
        environment: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PAY_ENVIRONMENT,
      })
    )
  }

  console.log('google pay client', paymentsClient)

  const cardPaymentMethod = useMemo(
    () => createCardPaymentMethod({ supportedCardBrands }),
    [supportedCardBrands]
  )

  const isReadyToPay = useCallback(() => {
    if (!paymentsClient) {
      console.log('isReadyToPay no client :-(((((')
      return Promise.resolve({ result: false })
    }

    const isReadyToPayRequest = {
      ...baseRequest,
      allowedPaymentMethods: [cardPaymentMethod],
    }

    console.log('isReadyToPay req', isReadyToPayRequest)

    return paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(isReadyToPayRequest).then((response) => {
      console.log('isReadyToPay res=', response)

      return response
    })
  }, [cardPaymentMethod, paymentsClient])

  const contextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      loading: !paymentsClient,
      paymentsClient,
      cardPaymentMethod,
      isReadyToPay,
    }),
    [cardPaymentMethod, isReadyToPay, paymentsClient]
  )

  return (
    <GooglePayContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <Script src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js" onReady={handleReady} />
      {children}
    </GooglePayContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: WebViews are not supported at the moment. The only way would be to bridge to native code: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/support/faq#:~:text=Does%20the%20Google%20Pay%20API%20integration%20work%20in%20WebViews%3F